# Cleaning up unused Customers

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am being asked to clean unused Customers in our AX database. The challenge is defining "unused" of course.

Is there any diagram anywhere documenting the table's relationship in Dynamics AX 2009 ?

For example, I see the table `LedgerJournalTrans` has the "`AccountNum`" field. I guess I could extrapolate that if a Customer has no associated records in `LedgerJournalTrans`, it is unused but I think it may be a bit more complicated than this.

Anything else I should watch for ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had to do this before, and it really isn't terribly challenging, you just have to do your due diligence.  I wouldn't feel as confident with ian_scho's method because it only checks two tables, but I'd say his method gets the 80%.

I would say your best method is to copy the class **`Classes\InventUnusedDimCleanUp`** and modify the simple functions in the **`\run`** method.

This is a base class that basically does the following, except I'm going to substitute `InventDimId` with `AccountNum` for solidarity:

- Insert every customer account (`AccountNum`) into an empty **check table** as a starting reference
- Traverse the `Data Dictionary\Tables` tree node over every table in the AOT
- While traversing, determine if the table is a candidate table to compare against
- If it is a candidate table, then traverse each field and determine if it's a candidate field by checking if it is an EDT of `CustAccount` or an EDT that extends it
- If we determine it is a candidate field, then insert that into our container list of `[TableId,FieldId]`s
- Next, loop through the container and for each tableId/fieldId, delete from our check table `AccountNum`'s that **DO** exist in the candidate tables, so that we will be left with a **check table** of `AccountNum`'s that were not found in any table
- Lastly, a step you will probably do manually, but it will delete from `CustTable` the customers that are remaining in the **check table**, which have been deemed **unused**

This should accomplish your task, but doesn't take in account any external systems or customization you may have...but it gets the 95%.

Comment: "ian_scho's method only checks two tables" - I agree Alex!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget customer transactions - In one company or across all of them?
And in AX 2012 the financial dimension framework *may* reference the customer table itself.

```
CustTable custTable;
CustTrans custTrans;
//DefaultDimensionView defaultDimensionView; // **AX 2012**
;
//Customer transactions not found.
setPrefix("@SYS119665");

while select crossCompany AccountNum, Party from custTable 
    notExists join custTrans 
    where custTable.AccountNum == custTrans.AccountNum
{   
    info (strFmt("%1 - %2", custTable.AccountNum, custTable.name()));

    //// Check financial dimension definition, 'Customer' **AX 2012**
    //select firstonly defaultDimensionView 
    //    where defaultDimensionView.DisplayValue == custTable.AccountNum
    //    && defaultDimensionView.Name == "Customer";  //"Client" in some countries?  May depend upon AX installation.
    //if (defaultDimensionView)
    //{        
    //    warning("Financial dimension value exists.");
    //}
}
```

Personally I'd advise against deleting ANYTHING on these systems.  Produce a report about what percentage of master data is being used, and if the data negatively impacts on usability...
Then see if your boss forgets about the request :)